# Using dynamic content in first level path using express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm currently working on an express app, and I encounter a curious case. I usually define my routes as host/blog/:articleId or host/blog, however in this case, I'm using host/:articleId. Obviously I defined it at the bottom of the routes in order to not mess up high level routes like host/contact or host/about-us.

Is this consider a bad practice or can cause my application fail at some level? The main motivation is for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem if you could be sure that there not be an articleId = "contact" or "about-us"